# Does $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}}{ x^2 + 1} \,dx $ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Does the following integral converge? I will post my solution, but I am unsure if it is true.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}}{ x^2 + 1} \,dx $$

---

**My solution:**
I will use limit comparison test.

Let $$ f(x) = \frac{e^{-2x}}{ x^2 + 1}$$ and $$ g(x) = \frac {e^{-2x}}{x^2} $$

Then $$ \lim_{ x \to +\infty } \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{ x \to +\infty } \frac{\frac{e^{-2x}}{x^2 + 1}}{\frac {e^{-2x}}{x^2}} = \lim_{ x \to \infty } \frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1} =  1 - \lim_{ x \to \infty } \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} = 1  $$

Whatever whatever one does, so does the other

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) dx =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}}{ x^2 }  dx  = e^{-2}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{3-1} *e^{-x}dx = e^{-2}*Γ(3) = e^{-2}*3! = e^{-2}*6$$

Therefore g(x) converges, thus f(x) converges.

Is this right? I'm totally not confident about it.

---

Apparently on my solution silly mistakes were made.
$$ e^{-2x} \neq e^{-x} * e^{-2} $$
and $$\frac {1}{x^2} \neq x^{3-1} $$

**Thanks for the great answers.** Sometimes the solution is east and in front of you but you fail to see it

Comment: I think it is easier to say $x^2+1\geq 1$, then the integrand is always less or equal than $e^{-2x}$ which has finite integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not O.K., since $e^{-2}e^{-x}=e^{-(x+2)}$ and not $= e^{-2x}$and $ \frac{1}{x^2} \ne x^{3-1}.$

My solution: let $g(x)=e^{-2x}$ then we have $0 \le f \le g$ on $[0, \infty)$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) dx$ is convergent.

$\int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) dx=1/2$.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}}{ x^2 + 1} \,dx
\;\leqslant\;
\int_{0}^{\infty} \!e^{-2x} \,dx
=-\frac12e^{-2x}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}
=\frac12
$$
and
$$
\frac{e^{-2x}}{ x^2 + 1} \geqslant0
$$
Thus the integral is well-defined and finite.

Comment: Ooops ! $\frac12e^{-2x}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}=\frac12.$

Comment: @Fred: Thanks, un-Ooops'ed.

Answer (score 3):

Just easier, $$\left|\frac{e^{-2x}}{1+x^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2},$$
which is integrable.